# Formal definition of a bijective proof (in combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics, proof-theory

In the Princeton Companion to Mathematics, in a section on combinatorics, the author claimed that there are generally two ways to prove statements in combinatorics. The first, more preferred method, is a bijective proof, that is, a proof where you exhibit an explicit bijection between two sets, to prove that two sets have equal cardinality. The other method, is by manipulating algebraic expressions, which is often derogatorily called "manipulatorics". But, my question is, what is the formal definition of a bijective proof? Sure, we all know it when we see it, but is there a formal definition of such a thing? This is similar to my question on the formal definition of constructive proofs. I would be very glad to know if there is a formal definition of bijective proof somewhere, and as a bonus, a statement in combinatorics that can be proved by "manipulatorics" but not by a bijective proof, along with the proof that there is no bijective proof of that statement.

Comment: What's wrong with the definition stated in the question? Seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Formally: We define that two sets have the same cardinality exactly when there exists a bijective map between them .  Therefore: If you can demonstrate that a bijection does exist, then you have proven equal cardinality.  That is all.

Comment: As for your "bonus" I'm not sure any such problems exist.  There are, however, many problems in enumerative combinatorics for which a solution is known but no bijective proof is known.

Comment: As to "manipulatorics", it is unappreciated only because proof by algebraic rules doesn't always lead to easy comprehension.  "Well sure, the maths works out okay, but I still don't grok *why* are these things equal!"

Comment: See this discussion on Math Overflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323779/what-is-an-explicit-bijection-in-combinatorics. It seems hard even for experts to nail down exactly what is meant by a bijective proof.

Answer (score 1):

In combinatorics we are interested in finding the number of elements of some sets. Defining a bijection between two sets gives us information that these two sets have the same number of elements. This is what I would call a 'bijective proof'.
For example, given a finite set $X$ with $n$ elements we would like to know the number of elements of a set $2^X$, i.e. the set of all subsets of $X$. We can define a function $\varphi\colon 2^X\to \{0,1\}^X$ and $\psi\colon \{0,1\}^X\to 2^X$ by the formulae
$$\varphi(A)(x) = \begin{cases}1;&x\in A\\ 0;&x\notin A,\end{cases},\quad \psi(f) = \{x\in X\ |\ f(x)=1\}$$ and prove that $\varphi\circ\psi = \mathrm{id}_{\{0,1\}^X}$ and $\psi\circ\varphi = \mathrm{id}_{2^X}$. This shows that $\varphi$ is a bijection, so the considered sets have the same number of elements. If we already know that $\#\{0,1\}^X=2^n$ then we proved that $\#2^X=2^n$.